# Server Unreachable SonarQube Webhook to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We have got two servers, one running Jenkins inside a Docker Swarm and another running SonarQube. For the last few years, Jenkins pipelines successfully triggered Sonar scans and webhooks reported back to Jenkins.

But after a SSL certificate renewal(on an ALB of the swarm) on the Jenkins side, the webhooks just constantly say "Server Unreachable". The URL for jenkins has not been changed at all.

[image]

And on the jenkins side, the log just waits for the quality gate to timeout.

```
SonarQube task 'AXz95fbXYt_5WKK0bZ00' status is 'IN_PROGRESS'
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
```

The `Jenkinsfile` looks something like this in the quality gate stage:

```
timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {                    
         waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
     }
```

Comment: Very interesting. I just checked to see if you're in my company, because we saw the exact same thing happen on the day that SSL was changed on the Jenkins instance, and it's been failing that way ever since. No one has been able to figure this out. We've had to implement workarounds. I guess I'll provide some workaround ideas in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is to get the root cause of the problem. FWIW, the "Server Unreachable" message is shown whenever the http status code is not >= 200 and < 300. Part of the detail of why it is so is in these lines of code:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/HEAD/server/sonar-web/src/main/js/apps/webhooks/components/DeliveryItem.tsx#L40

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/HEAD/sonar-ws/src/main/java/org/sonarqube/ws/client/BaseResponse.java#L28

(when delivery.httpStatus is not filled because it was not successful, the message "Server Unreachable" is shown).

But since that message is not helpful, you need to get the actual error message. To do it, you need to change the log level to DEBUG or TRACE ("Administration" page, "System" tab, "Log levels" setting). Then you need to reproduce the problem with the webhook. Then you download the logs of the Compute Engine, and you will get a line like this:

DEBUG ce[xxxxxx][o.s.s.w.WebHooksImpl] Failed to send webhook 'Jenkins' | url=https://yourjenkins/sonarqube-webhook/ | message=unable to find valid certification path to requested target

So, the problem is that the SSL certificate of the Jenkins server is not trusted by the SonarQube server (which acts as http client), which is typical of self-signed certificates, or signed by a root certificate authority (CA) created by your organization.

The solution is to add the CA root certificate to the cacerts file of the Java installation used by the SonarQube server. For SonarQube running on Windows this is typically the file %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, we ran into almost exactly the same sequence of events.  On the day they reconfigured SSL on our Jenkins instance, our webhooks from SonarQube to Jenkins started failing. That was more than a year ago. We've never found any clue to why this is happening.

At some point, I came to the conclusion that this would never be fixed, so I decided to figure out a workaround.  It's helpful to understand the logic that happens in "waitForQualityGate".  The first thing that it does is make a REST call to SonarQube to determine whether the background task is complete.  If it is not, it goes into a wait loop for the completion of the task, which will not complete successfully.

So, the workaround is to ensure that when "waitForQualityGate" starts, we make sure that the background task is complete.  There are two ways to do this.  There's one strategy that is very simple, but has drawbacks, and there's a slightly more complex strategy that is smarter.

The very simple strategy is simply to add a "sleep" before "waitForQualityGate".  How long you sleep really depends.  If you sleep too short, some background tasks might not have completed by then, going into the loop again.  If you sleep too long, then you waste time sitting there doing nothing useful.

The better strategy is to essentially use the same logic used in "waitForQualityGate", making the REST call to SonarQube to check on the status of the background task, in a retry loop, and exiting the loop when the status reports that the task is complete.

The logic for this would look something like this:

```
String authString = "${sonarProps['sonar.login']}:${sonarProps['sonar.password']}"
// If webhooks aren't going to work, then we have to poll for the task ourselves. First, we have to figure
// out the task id.
def reportFilePath = "target/sonar/report-task.txt"
def reportTaskFileExists = fileExists "${reportFilePath}"
if (reportTaskFileExists) {
    echo "Found report task file"
    def taskProps = readProperties file: "${reportFilePath}"
    echo "taskId[${taskProps['ceTaskId']}]"
    while (true) {
        sleep 20
        def taskStatusResult    =
            sh(returnStdout: true,
               script: "curl -s -X GET -u ${authString} \'${sonarProps['sonar.host.url']}/api/ce/task?id=${taskProps['ceTaskId']}\'")
            echo "taskStatusResult[${taskStatusResult}]"
        def taskStatus  = new JsonSlurper().parseText(taskStatusResult).task.status
        echo "taskStatus[${taskStatus}]"
        // Status can be SUCCESS, ERROR, PENDING, or IN_PROGRESS. The last two indicate it's
        // not done yet.
        if (taskStatus != "IN_PROGRESS" && taskStatus != "PENDING") {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is very similar to you indeed! The only solution would be to add the SSL Cert on the Sonar's servers but the team was not very confident in doing it as the server itself was maintained by 3rd party vendors. But what we are currently doing is to change the cert on our Jenkins server to Public. Will keep you posted on what happens. Thanks again.